# Chrome extension: empty URL bar on created tabs

Tags: url, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently, I'm working on an extension for Chrome, which is great fun so far, but now I encountered a little problem.

Generally, tabs that contain a file of the plugin have an empty URL bar (I'm using Chrome 13.xx), like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

This tab was created by the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: chrome.extension.getURL('../relative/path/to/a/file.html')
}, function(newTab){
  ...
});
```

It would be nice to have the URL visible, so it can be shared with other people who have the same extension installed (the URL has a unique ID for the extension, if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible for the time being. See issue 72021 for Chromium:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72021

You might just want to include the URL somewhere on the page and make it easy to copy for users (e.g. an `<input type="text">` box wouldn't be much more intrusive than the URL bar itself).

Comment: Thanks for the link and possible solution (:

Comment: The bug has been fixed in Chrome 28.